# Examples with Haskell-src-exts package

Tags: parsing, haskell, haskell-src-exts

I'm working with Haskell and I want to build a typechecker for this language. To do this I need a way to parse it and I know that Haskell-src-exts suits the job well. However I don't have the slightest idea of how this package works; I've tried to find some examples/ tutorials on the internet without any result. Can anyone help me? Does anyone know some tutorial, or maybe can reference me a book which contains examples abouth this package? I'm also open to try another package, if it is well described and it comes with a load of examples.

Comment: Hi Enrico, welcome to stack overflow. Unfortunately, this type of question is typically closed. Here are some articles to read that discuss appropriate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 

Questions specifically asking for tutorials and books are deemed inappropriate. Perhaps another commenter can give you better guidance on where to go to get this addressed. I did a quick google search and didn't find much either.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In the future I will be more careful on posting questions.

Comment: Well, it's still open and you got an answer from a high reputation member. So it's working out so far. With at least an entry into the library you may find the rest of the docs a little easier going. I've had my fair share of issues trying to make headway with a Haskell module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convenient entry point is `parseFile`.  If the following program is used to parse itself:

```
module HelloParser where

import Language.Haskell.Exts

main = print =<< parseFile "HelloParser.hs"
```

then it produces the parsed output (stripped of `SrcSpanInfo` values and reformatted):

```
ParseOk
  (Module (Just (ModuleHead (ModuleName "HelloParser") Nothing Nothing)) []
    [ ImportDecl { importModule = ModuleName "Language.Haskell.Exts"
                 , importQualified = False
                 , importSrc = False
                 , importSafe = False
                 , importPkg = Nothing
                 , importAs = Nothing
                 , importSpecs = Nothing} ]
    [ PatBind
      (PVar (Ident "main"))
      (UnGuardedRhs (InfixApp
                      (Var (UnQual (Ident "print")))
                      (QVarOp (UnQual (Symbol "=<<")))
                      (App
                        (Var (UnQual (Ident "parseFile")))
                        (Lit (String "HelloParser.hs" "HelloParser.hs")))))
      Nothing ])
```

which seems relatively readable.

To complete the task of type checking Haskell, I don't think there's any way to avoid individual consideration of the hundreds of parse tree data types and constructors in `Language.Haskell.Exts.Syntax` and the other package modules, so I'm not sure how much further a more in-depth tutorial can get you.